# Why Does ParameterizedThreadStart Only Allow Object Parameter?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Please let me know why **ParameterizedThreadStart** class only allow method which only System.object argument type contain.

```
public class MainThreadTest
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread T = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(DisplayYOrX));
        T.Start("X");

        DisplayYOrX("Y");
    }

    static void DisplayYOrX(object outValue)
    {
        string Parameter = (string)outValue;

        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            Console.Write(Parameter);
    }
}
```

Why I would like to know about that is I do not want to use type cast syntax again.

```
string Parameter = (string)outValue;
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reason for the limitation is that `ThreadStart` isn't a generic delegate and hence it's only capable of passing an `object` around.  This is easy enough to work around though by using a lambda where you directly pass the value.

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  ThreadStart start = () => { 
    DisplayYOrX("X");
  };
  Thread t = new Thread(start);
  t.Start();

  ...
}

static void DisplayYOrX(string outValue) {
  ...
}
```

Version for C# 2.0

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  ThreadStart start = delegate { 
    DisplayYOrX("X");
  };
  Thread t = new Thread(start);
  t.Start();

  ...
}
```

Comment: I think , as for developer who use 2.0 .net framework, lambda is hard to use. Am i correct ?

Comment: @Frank I just updated my answer to include a version that will work with the 2.0 C# compiler. Note: The use of lambda syntax is valid even in the 2.0 framework provided you use the C# 3.0 or higher compiler.  Either way, the second sample I put up there will work with everything C# 2.0 and above

Comment: I really interest the way you said that we could use lambda syntax in 2.0 framework. So, could you please tell me how could we do it. Any reference links?

Comment: @Frank you can use the C# 3.0 compiler or VS 2008 and above and set the project to target the 2.0 runtime.  The feature is called multitargeting and there is a nice overview here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398197(v=vs.90).aspx